# Java recursive drawing

Tags: java, recursion

This is an assignment, so I'd prefer an explanation more than straight code.
The task is to draw circles recursively like the picture [image: Recursive circles]

I can't work out the pattern to draw it though. A turtle class is used to draw the circles.
This is what I've managed so far

```
private void draw(int level, double size){
   if(level < 0) return;
   turtle.setPenDown(true);
   turtle.drawOval(size);
   //Here I think there needs to be code to move to the positions of the other circles?
   draw(level-1,size/2);

}
```

But of course it only draws this at the moment: [image: My drawing so far]

EDIT:

Maybe some code could help, this isn't going to well for me.

Comment: What does level mean? How many circles per level?

Comment: Does it have to be recursive? This task doesn't actually strike me as one where recursion would be useful.

Comment: At level 0, there is 1 circle, at level one there are 4, and level 2 there are 16 and so forth

Comment: For the assignment, yes it does. Whether its practical, probably not...

Comment: This can be done very easily. The amount of circles being through `amt = 1 << level`, `num = amt * amt`. Consider using that.

Answer (score 1):

If it's got to be recursive then I would suggest something like the following, I'll just talk algorithm wise since you asked to not have code come back.

If we're going to think of this as a long series of self-similar circles then the general process is pretty straightforward.

1. Check if there are n circles in your current row. The row is defined as whatever direction is forward/backward for your turtle. If you want you could store the circles drawn in a 2-d list or array to make checking easier.
2. If there are n circles, then turn right, otherwise draw a circle and move forward.

That will draw the circles from the outside in. If you want it from the inside out it probably makes less sense to do recursion but it would be something like this:

1. Function: Draw circle. Turn right if you can, otherwise move forward.
2. Stop when the total number of circles is equal to n^2

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks :) It would probably defeat the whole point of the assignment if I was just spoon feed the code. I'll give that a go and see what happens!

Comment: @Lift You could also include a double for loop inside the recursive function (running until level ^ 2) that determines the position of the circle, then just pass *level*
 down.